# What is the difference between using const and function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

What is the difference between these two functions?

```
const square = (number) => {
  return number * number;
};

function square (number) {
  return number * number;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: Your function will never get overridden by some other js file having same function name in case you declare it as const. The definition will remain exactly the same, whatever be the case.

Answer (score 2):

There are several.

First, const prevents reassignment of the name `square` while function does not. Second, using an arrow function doesn't have it's own lexical context, so it won't have a scoped `this` and can't be used as a constructor. For reference, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Note you can also do:

```
  const square = function(num) { return num * num }
```

Which both prevents reassignment and creates a lexical context.

Comment: Arrow functions create a new scope, otherwise the `var` in `() => {var a =8}` would be accessible outside of the arrow function.

Comment: Sorry, meant lexical context, not scope. Fixed @t.niese

Comment: What do you mean by lexical context?

Comment: @michelle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295265/lexical-scope-in-javascript