# Remove THIS element after change it's class

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to delete element 'this' ,500ms after changing its class, but it does not work

```
     $('.card').click(function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).remove();
                console.log('removed');
            },500);
            $(this).toggleClass("card card-used");
     });
```

and HTML

```
<div class="card">asdasd</div>
```

I can see "removed" in my console log but it wasn't remove()

Comment: `this` exists within the click function, not the function you pass to setTimeout.

Comment: To expand on my above comment, `this` ion your example refers to the window object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use arrow function to inherit **this** from the parent scope i.e .card , as **this** inside setTimeout function refers to window object

Please refer this link for more details- [Lexical Scope in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295265/lexical-scope-in-javascript)

```js
$('.card').click(function() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                $(this).remove();
                console.log('removed');
            },500);
            $(this).toggleClass("card card-used");
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">asdasd</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As already described, `this` belongs to the `click` context and cannot be accessed in the callback. But you can store it into a variable and access it in the callback.

```
$('.card').click(function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(self).remove();
            console.log('removed');
        },500);
        $(this).toggleClass("card card-used");
 });
```